# Multiple files upload chosen in the same browse file window (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

I've searched for "multiple files upload in ruby on rails" and the plugins that were suggested always displayed multiple `<input type="file" ...>` tags. I'm looking for something where I can choose multiple files in the same browse file window, like when uploading photos on facebook.

I've found [this one](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload), but it requires some under-the-hood coding to be used in RoR (it is ready for PHP).

My requirements are really basic: I only need to be able to upload files facebook-like. No visual effects needed, or progress bars or whatever. So maybe I'm thinking about implementing my own uploader, but I don't know where to start.

So if you got either 1) a suggestion of RoR plugin that might do what I just described or 2) tips on how to implement one myself, I'd be very glad to hear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard good things about [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) and, to a lesser extent, [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). The former uses a variety of techniques transparently to try and achieve multi-file upload (using the HTML5 API if possible); the latter only supports Flash (though this is what many users will end up using).

Integrating these with Rails is just a matter of implementing the API they expect, which is fairly straightforward.

Here is a post by someone who has taken the effort of making sure CSRF protection and Flash session cookies even co-operate. http://planetrails.com/plupload-with-rails-3

I have not followed that particular guide myself, but it seems correct.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Plupload seems to suit me very well!

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success with the [jQuery File Upload Plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). It uses both the HTML5 "multiple" attribute for file inputs and drag-and-drop uploading.

If you're using paperclip and jQuery, you can get it integrated in your app pretty quickly.